# How to simplify the IF ELSE statement C#?

Tags: c#, if-statement

```
if(currency.equal("CND"))
       if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(member.LastName))
                    {
                        return $"{member.FirstName}".Trim();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return $"{member.LastName} {member.FirstName}".Trim();
                    }

                else
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(member.LastName))
                    {
                        return $"{member.FirstName}".Trim();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return $"{member.FirstName} {member.LastName}".Trim();
                    }
```

I need to simplify this statement shorter but im not sure how? Im newbie in this stuff i might need some help on it.. any suggestion?

Comment: Does that compile?

Comment: it looks like the code is just dupe'd.

Comment: Please fix your code (there's a missing top-level if statement) so we can answer the question accurately.

Comment: just use the ? : operator (condition) ? res1 : res2; But as @Leo said, if it compiles and it is readable there is no need to put it in less statements. The compiler will treat it in the same way

Comment: @Zinov Disagree. This code is difficult to read. It should be reduced to increase readability - assuming you're not crunched on time.

Comment: @cwharris difficult to read in terms of the business logic? I don't think so, but as I said, you can put it in one line using the ? : operator, you can use a switch as well, but in my opinion should be clear enough from the business standpoint, and as well for the developers that will maintain the code later. But again is my opinion

Comment: @hunt can you take the time to fix that question? It's causing a lot of confusion otherwise this question will have to be closed. It's not quite clear what you're asking

Comment: @Grant already edited.Actually it got 2 condition so its quite confusing..

Comment: @Zinov readability isn't just about reading. The code's intent wasn't immediately obvious, nor was it obvious if there was a bug. The "CND" edit OP made helps clarify intent, but can you imagine if this code was expanded to more than two languages without changing the concatenation strategy? It would quickly become difficult to comprehend only as a series nested of if/else statements and similar strings.

Answer (score 3):

This does not necessarily simplifies it, it simply makes it a one-liner

```
return $"{(!member.LastName.IsNullOrEmpty() ? member.LastName : "")}{member.FirstName}".Trim();
```

However, for better clarity and readibility the `if/else` block is perfectly fine...

```
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(member.LastName))
        {
            return $"{member.FirstName}".Trim();
        }
        else
        {
            return $"{member.LastName} {member.FirstName}".Trim();
        }
```

I would definitely prefer the `if...else` block to using a one-line string interpolation

Comment: @hunt your current code doesn't compile. I'm assuming you were making a simple validation check on `LastName`. If my assumption is correct, then your current code is just fine

Comment: @hunt if your current code works, I'd just use it as it is. If there comes a time when you need to add different currencies, or use this code in multiple places, I'd probably move it in to its own method and redesign it for extensibility.

Answer (score 1):

You can move some of your code around to cut out the duplication. If the last name is missing, the first name is the only one to print, so test for that first. Then test for the condition that prints out the full name in the preferred order.

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(member.LastName))
{
    return member.FirstName.Trim();
}
else
{
    return currency.equal("CND")
        ? $"{member.LastName} {member.FirstName}".Trim()
        : $"{member.FirstName} {member.LastName}".Trim();
}
```

You could rewrite it as a nested ternary operation too, though it's no shorter really and whether it's more readable depends on the person reading it...

```
return (string.IsNullOrEmpty(member.LastName)
        ? member.FirstName
        : currency.equal("CND")
          ? $"{member.LastName} {member.FirstName}"
          : $"{member.FirstName} {member.LastName}").Trim();
```

Comment: hi just quick question in case in the future might add more currency can i use it in the same way?

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely over-engineered. Not shorter, but intent is clearer and it is easily extensible.

```
public static string GetDisplayName(Member member, string currency)
{
    return string.Join(" ", GetDisplayNameParts(member, currency));
}

public static IEnumerable<string> GetDisplayNameParts(Member member, string currency)
{
    switch (currency)
    {
        case "CND":
            yield return member.LastName ?? ""
            yield return member.FirstName ?? ""
            yield break;

        default:
            yield return member.FirstName ?? ""
            yield return member.LastName ?? ""
            yield break;
    }
}
```